# Change background color to tabhost

Tags: android, background, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I would like to change the background of the tabwidget in shown in the next image:

[image]

I would like to use a different background color, and change the font color to the selected tab. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this i used drawables for tab widgets instead of fixed images. my code is

```
tab1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_drawable));
```

in the tab_drawable is a simple selector defining the behavior of the drawable for different state. you can try that it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can google for the tables available for different colors
this is a chart or table available with color and the code to get that
color

just choose which ever you like

Comment: ... He wants to know how to *change* the color, not how to find a color to use.